# Android Emulator freezes

Tags: android, android-emulator

Until the last SDK release, my Android Emulator worked very nice with x86 architecture, installing Intel HAXM and enabling GPU for the device in AVD Manager.

With the latest SDK release, I reinstalled my Windows (from 8.0 to 8.1), tried both 1.06 and 1.07 Intel HAXM and my app freezes quite frequently.

It doesn't freeze to death, just the freezes/does not updates the screen anymore.

Especially if I'm swiping a ViewPager, then it freezes almost always in between pages.

BUT, if I click a menuitem on the AppBar, it refreshes itself and draws the destination ViewPage page.

I'd appreciate any advice, because right now app development via emulator became ultrapainful.

Answer (score 48):

My emulator froze and I couldn't fix it with the other answers, but this solved it:

1. Tools->**Device Manager**
2. In the *Actions* column for your virtual device, click the three dots on the right and then click **Wipe Data**.

This will clear the cache for the virtual device.

If your app depends on Google Play services, you will need to update it again

[Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006483/7732434) for "The selected AVD is currently running in the Emulator"

Comment: the easiest solution, and it worked for me too, thanks !

Comment: work for me thanks

Comment: I have some data in my sdcard. When I select Wipe Data it will erase all the data.Is there any other solution for it.

Comment: This not working, System freeze and also stop chrome browser or emulater or both.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

In the Android Virtual Device (AVD) settings, select
 - `edit this AVD`, then click
 - `show advanced setting` then
 - **DISABLE** `multi-core CPU`.

Comment: Do you have any reference, or can you explain why Disabling multi-core CPU might help ?

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. The error I was getting logged out before the emulator freezes up is: "Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: WHPX: Failed to set interrupt state registers, hr=c0350015". The closest I can find about what that MAY be is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507006/x86-pic-is-it-correct-for-qemu-to-raise-interrupts-on-all-cpus which, if this is the problem, would be why single core works, maybe!

Comment: Helped me. Thank you, stranger!

Comment: Apparently this option is not available in emulators since API 31

Comment: Worked for me api level 34 tab emulator

Answer (score 8):

In the Android Virtual Device (AVD) settings, turn off the **Use Host GPU** emulation option. Unfortunately, the resulting slowness is often worse than the freezing.

Comment: Yeah, You are right. UI is much slower, but it is always better than getting freezes. Thanks.

Comment: Come on, it is not slower, it is close to be dead. It is impossible to work with it in this mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. In my case, the speed is not bad at all!! Amazing find

Answer (score 5):

Before doing the steps you need to delete the **.lock** folder under the `C:\Users\user\.android\avd\yourEmulatorName\` path, To go there just simply click **Show on Desk** .Then -

**Step 1:** Go to **AVD Manager** and click the drop-down and select **Stop**. The emulator will be stopped then.

[image]

**Step 2:** Then click the **Cold Boot Now**

Answer (score 2):

Use the free [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx). It's very fast, and despite its name, does not require you to work in Visual Studio to use it. Android Studio and Eclipse happily detect it as the running emulator.

Comment: For use it, yow will need W8 or greatter O.S. Is not a good option if you still using w7

Answer (score 2):

Setting Boot option to Cold boot worked like a charm for me. Absolutely no idea why.

Also disabling advanced profiling helped me with older versions (API 21).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

stop the emulator and go to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.android\avd\Pixel_6_Pro_Edited_API_33.avd` and delete

`version_num.cache`

`cache.img.qcow2`

`cache.img`

`multiinstance.lock`

`hardware-qemu.ini.lock`

`AVD.conf`

it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to **use a lower version of SDK in emulator, namely the SDK version 31 (image "S")**
Please note the date I'm writing this, if you are seeing this in the future try lowering your version acccordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try giving virtual device less RAM.

Android froze on start with 4GB (=4096MB) RAM but did not freeze with 3GB (=3072MB).

Note: I'm using Android Studio on Linux Mint 21.1.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Visual Studio. Go to Android Device Manager and click the three dots. Click factory reset. This will also wipe any SD data or saved files.

Answer (score -2):

From the Android SDK Manager, install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) revision 5 or later, and then run `sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.msi` to update the drivers on your PC. This is version 1.1.0 of the accelerator, which seems to fix the freezing bug.

Comment: No, 1.1 still freezes.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
sdk\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -noaudio -no-boot-anim -avd Nexus5XAPI25 -prop monodroid.avdname=Nexus5XAPI25
```

After I added -noaudio option,it's ok

Comment: Can you explain what these options do to prevent freezing.  Do you have a link to explain the options ?