# The selected AVD is currently running in the Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I keep seeing the error message below in andriod studio. I am aware there are already posts that deal with this error. They specify that I go to the location C:\Users\XXXX.android\avd\ and delete the folder Pixel_API_25.avd and Pixel_API_25.ini. However I cannot delete these files as it says they are currently in use. I can't see where though?

```
The selected AVD is currently running in the Emulator. Please exit the emulator instance and try deleting again.
```

Comment: You can try to delete all .lock under .android. [Like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006483/6447158)

Answer (score 7):

AVD Pixel_3a_API_29 is already running.
If that is not the case, delete the files at

- In my case
- Go to C:\Users\xxxxx(system name)\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_29(emulator name folder)
- Delete folder hardware-qemu.ini.lock
- Go to Android Studio -> AVD Manager -> Relaunch emulator

Answer (score 5):

**For Windows**

- Go to FileManager.
- Go to `C://Users/nameOfYourSystem/.android/.avd`
- delete corresponding (selected AVD) configuration setting file.
- Go to Android Studio -> AVD Manager. Your AVD should not listed  here

**For MacOS**

- Open `YOUR_USERNAME/.android/avd`
- Delete the corresponding configuration setting file.

Comment: A warning message pops up!! The action can't be compeleted

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Kalai answer for MacOS

- In your terminal: `open YOUR_USERNAME/.android/avd`
- Delete corresponding configuration setting File.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can stop the AVD by ending the "qemu-system-x86_64.exe" process in the task-manager. After that you should be able to delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux:

- Go to: YOUR_USERNAME/.android/avd/NAME_OF_EMULATED_DEVICE (to show .hidefiles just press CTRL+H)
- Delete all files with .lock extension
- Relaunch emulator in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In Windows

To delete the AVD `pixel_3a_api_29`, you can follow the below steps:

1. Close the emulator instance if it is running.
2. Navigate to the location where the AVD is stored. For example, `C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.android\\avd\\Pixel_3a_API_29`.
3. Delete the folder `hardware-qemu.ini.lock`.
4. Go to Android Studio -> AVD Manager -> Relaunch emulator.

If you are unable to delete the files due to them being in use, try deleting all `.lock` files under `.android` directory ¹.

Still If you are unable to delete the files or folder

This error message usually occurs when the file is being used by another program. Here's what you can try:

1. Close Android Studio and all running emulators.
2. Open the **Task Manager** and end all processes related to `adb.exe`, `emulator.exe`, and `qemu-system-x86_64.exe`.
3. Navigate to the directory where the AVD is stored. For example, `C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.android\\avd\\Pixel_3a_API_29`.
4. Delete the folder `hardware-qemu.ini.lock`.
5. Relaunch Android Studio and the emulator.

If you are still unable to delete the file, try deleting all `.lock` files under `.android` directory ¹.

I hope this helps!