# AVD doesn't stop to consume disk space

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I don't have any android device so I need to use the AVD to test my app.

Unfortunately, and I can't understand why, the emulator doesn't stop to take all the space in my hard drive while I'm running the app (keep writing all the time and get all space). Now I have less than 2 GB of free disk space, and even if I delete all devices from AVD I can't get a lot of space back.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Need to unistall android studio?

**UPDATE**

Today I was able to free enough space to have 3 GB free space disk, so a created a new emulator and by lunch time I left my desk with the AVD emulator open and 2 GB free space disk. One hour later I came back and only have 500 KB left at my HD. I was testing an app with not even one writing task and he was on background state during my lunch time. Have no idea what to do.

Comment: I got the same problem with yours. Did you find any solution to avoid it?

Comment: Look for c:\users\<username>\.android\.avd folder. If you are creating avd over and over data of avd or deleted avd still exists here.

Comment: I have the same issue. Each AVD devices takes up around 8GB + the System Image (API Level 29, 30, 31, etc.) My solution has been to use one emulator targeting API Level 30. This seems to work, and only uses 18GB, but prevents me from QAing older API Levels or different device sizes and layouts.

Answer (score 3):

Look for

c:/users/username/.android/.avd

(Where username is the name of your windows user account.)

folder. If you are creating avd over and over data of avd or deleted avd still exists at this location.

Comment: Any idea as to why these aren't simply deleted?  I ran out of space and just happened to find emulators from 2+ years ago, freed up 12gb :O

Comment: @Jay.Smyth you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006483/3479888          if you are on windows you can check that avd folder in resource monitor ->  cpu -> search handles -> paste dir path and you will be able to see what's blocking the dir from deletion

Answer (score 2):

What is the size on disk of your AVDs?

[image]

Did you try to show on disk or wipe data?

[image]

What about their configuration?

[image]

You can try SpaceSniffer to see where is your storage going.

[image]

Delete Emulator’s Temp Files
temp folder which located in this directory `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator .`

[image]

Delete Old Version Android Studio

[image]

It isn't normal to your AVD taking up space, because they're empty. So...it's the application you're developing doing some write task? Maybe is the Android updating itself?

Comment: My temp directory is empty and i just have one version of android studio installed. Have no idea about what to do